# How do I render a template and its arguments manually in Serilog?

Tags: .net, serilog

How do I implement the following method?

```
string BuildSerilogMessage(string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues);
```

The arguments are the same as the ones accepted by `ILogger.Debug` etc.

The reason why I want this is because I want to preserve template/values in an intermediate exception which needs to have single string Message as well. It is basically something like this:

```
// this exception is designed to be easily loggable by serilog
[Serializable]
public class StructuredException : Exception {
    public string MessageTemplate { get; private set; }
    public object[] PropertyValues { get; private set; }

    public StructuredException(string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        : base(BuildMessage(messageTemplate, propertyValues))
    {
        MessageTemplate = messageTemplate;
        PropertyValues = propertyValues;
    }

    public StructuredException(Exception inner, string messageTemplate, params object[] propertyValues)
        : base(BuildMessage(messageTemplate, propertyValues), inner)
    {
        MessageTemplate = messageTemplate;
        PropertyValues = propertyValues;
    }

    private static string BuildMessage(string messageTemplate, object[] propertyValues) {
        // ???
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There's [an example in the Akka.NET repo](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/contrib/loggers/Akka.Logger.Serilog/Event/Serilog/SerilogLogMessageFormatter.cs#L19) of this being done, though only scalar values are supported in the arguments.

The basic notion is to use `MessageTemplateParser` to get the template:

```
var parser = new MessageTemplateParser();
var template = parser.Parse(messageTemplate);
```

Then zip the tokens from the template up with the arguments:

```
var properties = template.Tokens
    .OfType<PropertyToken>()
    .Zip(propertyValues, Tuple.Create)
    .ToDictionary(
        p => p.Item1.PropertyName,
        p => new ScalarValue(p.Item2));
```

Finally rendering:

```
var rendered = template.Render(properties);
```

(Apologies in advance for the bits that may not compile here.)

Comment: I used the snippet above but had to add a call to `.Distinct()` after `.OfType<PropertyToken>()` in order to deduplicate tokens that may appear more than once in the template.